# disconnect method not invoked if internet goes down in java mail api connection listener

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am facing an issue for ConnectionListener implementation in java mail on Store object.
My disconnect method and close method not called if I disconnect my internet connection.
My Code snippets are :

```
this.store.addConnectionListener(new ConnectionListenerImplmentedClass);  
this.store.connect(HOST, USER_NAME, PASSWORD);
```

---

```
    public void opened(ConnectionEvent e) {
    LOGGER.info("Connection opened...");
}

public void disconnect(ConnectionEvent e) {
    LOGGER.info("Connection opened...");
}

public void close(ConnectionEvent e) {
    LOGGER.info("Connection opened...");
}
```

Please suggest me where I am doing wrong...

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your operating system when and if you'll be notified if you "disconnect" your internet connection.  Usually you'll only be notified if you're actually doing something that uses the connection.  If your program is just sitting and waiting for events, you may never be notified.

Answer (score 1):

Going on what Bill Shannon said, it sounds like you need to perform a periodic check to see if the connection is still alive.  Javadocs suggest overriding the Service.isConnected() method in order to verify that any connection to the message store is still alive.

[http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Service.html#isConnected()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Service.html#isConnected%28%29)

**isConnected**

public boolean isConnected()
Is this service currently connected?
This implementation uses a private boolean field to store the connection state. This method returns the value of that field.

Subclasses may want to override this method to verify that any connection to the message store is still alive.

Returns:
true if the service is connected, false if it is not connected